# C#-converting array of byte to string gives weird output, does it mean the original value was coded?

Tags: c#, hex, byte

I am trying to convert a hex string to a string. But when I do it the result is gibberish. I also tried converting hex to byte array to string but that didn't work as well. I was told the first 2 bytes are just "headers" but I wanted to see what they look like as well

```
 string = "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\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\n\n"
```

This code is for getting to bytes and then converting it to string.

```
compString = compString.Substring(4);//taking the first 2 bytes out. 1 hex has 4 bits

byte[] byteArray = hexStringToByteArray(compString);
string result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray);

private byte[] hexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
{
    hexString = hexString.Replace("\n", "");

    int len = (hexString.Length - 2);
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2)
    {
        byte b = byte.Parse(hexString.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        byteArray[i / 2] = b;
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT- Output was weird because it was compressed. I needed to decompress it. Thanks everyone

Comment: That probably means those aren't ASCII bytes.

Comment: note all arrays of bytes are strings; bytes of values in the low non-printable range is very unusual for text, so: that probably isn't text (even if we ignore the first 2 bytes, there's a big chunk of 00000000, etc); where did the data come from?

Comment: @SLaks I tried UTF32, UTF7, and UTF8. I think it's suppose to be ASII

Comment: @dqv70219 no, based on the "01 00 06 ... 08 00 00 00 00 00 04 00", that definitely isn't ASCII, or *any other* text encoding... at least, not for any standard definition of "text"; so again: *where did this data come from*? To understand it, you need to be sure of what the rules are

Comment: There are also `\n`'s littered throughout that seem to cause some issues.

Comment: @MarcGravell the string is a value from a key from Redis CLI. It might have been compressed and/or serialized(not your protobuff though :( ), so I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: @RonBeyer I take care of getting rid of '\n' in my hexStringToByteArray method

Comment: @dqv70219 redis CLI (`redis-cli`) is just a tool for talking to redis - what the value *actually is* kinda matters. Since you mention redis: for all I know, that's a "hyperloglog" state (which gets stored in a redis `string` field using the `PF*` commands). Do you have *any context* on where this value came from? The one thing we can say pretty conclusively: it isn't a basic encoded text string